# VisualSVN moving repository from server1 to server2

Tags: svn, repository, visualsvn-server, svnadmin

I want to move my repository from server1 to say server2 . I have tried copying entire repository folder to server2, create a new repository from VisualSVN and select "Import Existing Repository" ("Repository (right click) --> All tasks --> Import Existing Repository") - but it gives an error "visualsvn "cannot import repository to the ancestor folder"

I tried running svnadmin dump, but its giving me below error.

> C:>svnadmin dump "c:\repos" > repos.dmp
>
> svnadmin: E720002: Can't open file 'C:\repos\format': The system cannot find the file specified.

In c:\repros - I have .svn, branches, tags and trunks folder.

I have VisualSVN version 2.5.3 on Server1 and 2.5.8 on Server2 incase version matters.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Looks like "C:\repros" is not a repository or a repositories root directory. It's a working copy. Check VisualSVN Server settings.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a modern VisualSVN Server version, consider using [VisualSVN Server PowerShell](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/powershell/) instead of `svnadmin`. See the list of cmdlets at https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/. The cmdlets you are looking for are [**Export-SvnRepository**](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Export-SvnRepository) and [**Import-SvnRepository**](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Import-SvnRepository).

`svnadmin` or `svnlook` tools operate on repositories. `C:\repos` is either a working copy (local user workspace, not a server-side database) or a repositories root directory, but not a repository. Therefore, you get the error.

In order to run `svnadmin dump`, `svnadmin hotcopy`, whaterver you have to provide a path to a repository. Assuming that your repositories are stored in C:\Repositories, the command should look like `svnadmin dump C:\Repositories\MyRepository`